# Redirect to different domain and URL structure

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to permanently redirect part of a website to a different domain and URL structure.

Everything that matches:
example.com/year/month/day/page-name/ 
and 
www.example.com/year/month/day/page-name/

Needs to redirect to:
www.sample.com/sub/sub2/year/month/page-name/

For example:
example.com/2013/11/09/a-great-page/

should permanently point to:
www.sample.com/sub/sub2/2013/11/a-great-page/

But I don't want to redirect any other pages on the site:
example.com/a-random-page
Shouldn't redirect anywhere.

My htaccess chops and regex skills are a little rusty, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `example.com` and `sample.com` are confusing similar... you should use different domain names in your example

Comment: Thought those were different enough. I'm not going to edit now though, since an answer already came in with my original domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[^/]+/?)$ http%2://sample.com/sub/sub2/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```