# how to 301 redirect an old url to a new url using apache redirect regex in aem6?

Tags: regex, redirect, aem

I have a requirement where I need to 301 redirect an old site URL to a new one. So the format of the URLs will be:

```
www.oldsite.com/test/xxx.pdf
```

should be redirected to

```
www.newsite/test/xxx.pdf.
```

So let's say, if someone hits `www.oldsite.com/test/123.pdf`, it should be redirected to `www.newsite/test/123.pdf`.

And 123 can be any number/name, so it should be replaceable using a RegEx.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to different domain and URL structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917589/redirect-to-different-domain-and-url-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(test/[^./]+\.pdf)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To go in your root .htaccess file on oldsite.com.